# Como mesclar um arquivo com outros vários arquivos, dinamicamente utilizando o grunt?

Tags: javascript, grunt

Eu estou com um problema que eu não consigo solucionar de forma alguma. O problema é o seguinte:

Eu utilizo o [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) para automatizar as tarefas dos meus projetos, e neste caso, eu estou utilizando ele da seguinte forma:

[image]

Como eu fiz no desenho acima, eu gostaria de pegar todos os arquivos Javascript da pasta "DEV" e juntar com o arquivo "scripts.js" para resultar em arquivos com o mesmo nome e subdiretório, mas localizados na pasta "JS". Eu queria fazer tudo isso dinamicamente, com diretórios e subdiretórios.

Meu código (de teste) é este:

```
extras2: {
  options: {
    log: true
  },
  expand: true, // set to true to enable options following options:
  cwd: '<%= dirs.folder %>dev/js', // all sources relative to this path
  src: ['**/*.js', '!**/scripts.js', '!**/_base/**'], // source folder patterns to match, relative to cwd
  dest: '<%= dirs.folder %>js', // destination folder path prefix
  ext: '.js' // replace any existing extension with this value in dest folder
}
```

Lembrando que o arquivo scripts está na pasta "dev".

Answer (score 3):

Para concatenar os arquivos, você precisa incluir a opção `concat` no seu `Gruntfile`:

```
concat: {
    options: {
        separator: ';'
    },
    dist: {
        src: ['dev/*.js'],
        dest: 'js/tudojunto.js'
    }
},
```

Comment: Então, me desculpe, pois eu não deixei claro como que seria a saída do arquivo. O arquivo que vem da pasta "Dev" vai ser compilado no mesmo diretório correspondente, só que na pasta "Js", e é claro, com o arquivo "scripts.js" mesclado.

Comment: Não sei se entendi, mas editei a resposta, veja se é isso que procura.

Comment: Antes de tudo, muito obrigado pela ajuda. Então, os arquivos de saída serão iguais aos de entrada, ou seja, o grunt não vai gerar apenas um arquivo, mas sim multiplos arquivos com o mesmo nome e subdiretório. A ideia é mais ou menos essa: dev/scripts.js + dev/arquivo1.js = js/arquivo1.js, outro exemplo: dev/scripts.js + dev/classes/arquivo2.js = js/classes/arquivo2.js

Comment: Hm, aí já é algo que eu nunca fiz, na verdade não sei muito do Grunt. Vamos esperar então, deve aparecer alguém que sabe mais que eu e possa te dar uma resposta decente.

Comment: Realmente, isso é meio complicado. Eu tive esse mesmo problema com o .less, porém no less ainda tem como usar o "@import" para importar um determinado código durante a conversão para css. O código que eu coloquei acima, foi baseado na solução que eu encontrei no caso do less. No caso do .js, eu pesquisei, tentei várias vezes, mas não consegui nenhum resultado. Mesmo assim obrigado pela ajuda!